# I can't install anything in my Ubuntu 18.04 - "package ideservice needs to be reinstalled"

Tags: apt, package-management

When I want to install or upgrade something this message appears:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package ideservice needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I try to solve it but I am desperate, I've checked other forums but it´s the same, please I need help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to: `sudo dpkg --remove --force-all ideservice`

Comment: -1 for unnecessary `--force-all` that may suppress other issues and hose the package management system even more.

Comment: well that works but now this message:

Comment: E: Malformed entry 2 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: @LuisGermánGarcíaSalinas show `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.lis` output.

Comment: When you give advice like this it is useful to explain what the command does and if possible link to a page which describes the process in more detail.